# How set a default props for a component in Quasar Framework?

Tags: quasar-framework

I'm building a web application using [Quasar Framework](https://quasar-framework.org) + node.js + webpack. Application was build using Quasar CLI.

I want to set the `q-tooltip` delay `prop` from default 0ms to 1000ms in all instances of `q-tooltip`, so every time a tooltip is used it will be automatically set to delay=1000ms.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Beginning with Quasar 17.1, you can now set defaults:

> Should you wish to set up some defaults, rather than specifying them each time, you can do so by using quasar.conf > framework > config > notify: {…} or by calling Notify.setDefaults({...}) or this.$q.notify.setDefaults({...}).

https://quasar-framework.org/components/notify.html#Setting-Up-Defaults